# Regular expression allow but don't require leading and trailing whitespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, whitespace, removing-whitespace

I have an email form.

I need to allow, but not require, any leading and trailing whitespace.

Right now I have `/^\s*[-a-z0-9_+\.]+\@([-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z0-9]{2,4}\s*$/i`

The problem with that, is that requires at least one leading and trailing whitespace.

Any ideas?

Comment: `\s*` is "zero or more whitespace characters" which is exactly what you are asking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just needed some paren:

```
^(\s*)[-a-z0-9_+\.]+@([-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z0-9]{2,4}(\s*)$
```